# IllegalArgumentException while creating Notification inside a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, exception, android-notifications

I am using the following code to create a Notification inside the `onRecieve` method of my `BroadcastReceiver` but it is giving me the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required`

### The code:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String tickerText;
    String expandedText;
    String expandedTitle;
    int icon;
    long when;
    Notification notification;

    int notificationref = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
    icon = R.drawable.reminder;
    tickerText = "New Reminder";
    when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    expandedText = "Reminder at: "
            + DateOrTimeString.getTimeString(task.time) + "\n"
            + task.detail;
    expandedTitle = "Reminder:" + task.topic;
    Intent intentDestroyer = new Intent(context, RemindHomeActivity.class);
    intentDestroyer.putExtra("ID", task.id);
    intentDestroyer.putExtra("NOTIFICATIONREF", notificationref);
    launchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationref,
            intentDestroyer, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, expandedTitle, expandedText,
            null);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

One more thing this problem is only in API level less than 11. it is wortking in API level 15  Icecream Sandwitch

Comment: Full stack trace please,with error line in source code

Comment: Like other Exceptions, It does not show the Line Number of Exception in DDMS

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the contentIntent

```
void android.app.Notification.setLatestEventInfo(Context context, CharSequence contentTitle, CharSequence contentText, PendingIntent contentIntent)‬
```

in your case:

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, expandedTitle, expandedText,
            launchIntent );
```